# From python web scrape into mysql

Tags: mysql, python-2.7, web-scraping

I am using python 2.7(on windows).The code extracts all the various fields from the website and prints it out onto the screen.Is there a way I could get the data directly into mysql database,or possibly into a csv file for exporting into a database.

```
 from urllib2 import urlopen
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
 html = urlopen("http://www.gbgb.org.uk/resultsMeeting.aspx?id=135682" )

 bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html)
 nameList = bsObj. findAll("div" , {"class" : "track"})
 for name in nameList:
  print(name. get_text())

 from urllib2 import urlopen
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
 html = urlopen("http://www.gbgb.org.uk/resultsMeeting.aspx?id=135682" )

 bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html)
 nameList = bsObj. findAll("div" , {"class" : "date"})
 for name in nameList:
  print(name. get_text())
 from urllib2 import urlopen
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
 html = urlopen("http://www.gbgb.org.uk/resultsMeeting.aspx?id=135682" ) 


 bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html)
 nameList = bsObj. findAll("div" , {"class" : "datetime"})
 for name in nameList:
  print(name. get_text())
 from urllib2 import urlopen
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
 html = urlopen("http://www.gbgb.org.uk/resultsMeeting.aspx?id=135682")   




 bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html)
 nameList = bsObj. findAll("div" , {"class" : "grade"})
 for name in nameList:
  print(name. get_text())
 from urllib2 import urlopen
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
 html = urlopen("http://www.gbgb.org.uk/resultsMeeting.aspx?id=135682"  )  



 bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html)
 nameList = bsObj. findAll("div" , {"class" : "distance"})
 for name in nameList:
  print(name. get_text())
  from urllib2 import urlopen
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
 html = urlopen("http://www.gbgb.org.uk/resultsMeeting.aspx?id=135682" )



 bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html)
 nameList = bsObj. findAll("div" , {"class" : "prizes"})
 for name in nameList:
  print(name. get_text())
 from urllib2 import urlopen
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
 html = urlopen("http://www.gbgb.org.uk/resultsMeeting.aspx?id=135682" ) 


 bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html)
 nameList = bsObj. findAll("li" , {"class" : "first essential fin"})
 for name in nameList:
  print(name. get_text())
 from urllib2 import urlopen
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
 html = urlopen("http://www.gbgb.org.uk/resultsMeeting.aspx?id=135682" ) 

 bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html)
 nameList = bsObj. findAll("li" , {"class" : "essential greyhound"})
 for name in nameList:
  print(name. get_text())
 from urllib2 import urlopen
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
 html = urlopen("http://www.gbgb.org.uk/resultsMeeting.aspx?id=135682" ) 


 bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html)
 nameList = bsObj. findAll("li" , {"class" : "trap"})
 for name in nameList:
  print(name. get_text())
 from urllib2 import urlopen
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
 html = urlopen("http://www.gbgb.org.uk/resultsMeeting.aspx?id=135682" ) 

bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html)
 nameList = bsObj. findAll("li" , {"class" : "sp"})
 for name in nameList:
  print(name. get_text())
 from urllib2 import urlopen
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
 html = urlopen("http://www.gbgb.org.uk/resultsMeeting.aspx?id=135682" )

 bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html)
 nameList = bsObj. findAll("li" , {"class" : "timeSec"})
 for name in nameList:
  print(name. get_text())
 from urllib2 import urlopen
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
 html = urlopen("http://www.gbgb.org.uk/resultsMeeting.aspx?id=135682" ) 

 bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html)
 nameList = bsObj. findAll("li" , {"class" : "timeDistance"})
 for name in nameList:
  print(name. get_text())
 from urllib2 import urlopen
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
 html = urlopen("http://www.gbgb.org.uk/resultsMeeting.aspx?id=135682" ) 

 bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html)
 nameList = bsObj. findAll("li" , {"class" : "essential trainer"})
 for name in nameList:
  print(name. get_text()) 
 from urllib2 import urlopen
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
 html = urlopen("http://www.gbgb.org.uk/resultsMeeting.aspx?id=135682" ) 

 bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html)
 nameList = bsObj. findAll("li" , {"class" : "first essential comment"})
 for name in nameList:
  print(name. get_text())  
 from urllib2 import urlopen
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
 html = urlopen("http://www.gbgb.org.uk/resultsMeeting.aspx?id=135682" ) 


 bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html)
 nameList = bsObj. findAll("div" , {"class" : "resultsBlockFooter"})
 for name in nameList:
  print(name. get_text())
```

Comment: Connect to your database and insert from code?

Comment: I can connect to the DB(mysql) but how do I get the data from screen into the database programatically?

Comment: learn SQL and how to use database with python.

Comment: btw: in one script you can import modules once. And you can create `html` and `bsObj` once.